# Calculate Center of Rotation Given Two Points - Perpendicular Bisector Method Doesn't Always Work

Tags: geometry

Given two points, $A$ and $B$ (in 2D space), and their post-rotation corresponding selves $A'$ and $B'$, most all examples describe the point of rotation as the intersection of perpendicular bisectors to $AA'$ and $BB'$.

This is fine if the points $A$ and $B$ aren't co-linear with the center of rotation, but... what if they are?

It seems odd that the most commonly used method for determining rotation center doesn't even work for points that are, for example, all on the x-axis. Or one where $A$ rotates around $B$.

Is there a more general method to find the rotation center point given any two points, co-linear or not?

Comment: You're right.  The method must make provision for this special case, where the common bisector is intersected with the the line $AB$ to find the center of rotation.

Comment: Can we assume we have Cartesian coordinates for all four points in the question, or do you require a solution in synthetic (pure) geometry?

Comment: @DavidK Assuming cartesian coordinates is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use a $3\times1$ column vector to represent each point.
The elements of this column vector are the $x$ coordinate of the point,
the $y$ coordinate of the point, and $1$.
For convenience, let's also use the same name for the column vector as for the point,
relying on context for disambiguation,
so if the letter $A$ appears in a matrix product, it refers to the column vector
and not the geometric point.

For example, if $A$ has coordinates $(a_x,a_y)$, then we have
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} a_x \\ a_y \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}. $$

First solve for $h$ and $k$ in the following matrix multiplication:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & h \\ 0 & 1 & k \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} A = A'. $$

The solution is $h = a'_x - a_x$, $k = a'_y - a_y$.

Next, solve for $c$ and $s$ in the matrix equation

$$ \begin{bmatrix} c & s & 0 \\ -s & c & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & h \\ 0 & 1 & k \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} B = B'. $$

This can be treated as a system of two linear equations in two unknowns.
Note that you will not get a unique solution if $s = 0$, but in that case you have a rotation by angle zero, which you could have detected by observing that $A = A'$ and $B = B'$; in that case, any point can be the center of rotation.

Now solve for $p_x$ and $p_y$ in

$$ \begin{bmatrix} c & s & 0 \\ -s & c & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & h \\ 0 & 1 & k \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}. $$

This too can be treated as a system of two linear equations in two unknowns.

Then the center of rotation is at coordinates $(x,y)$.

---

The coordinate solution above is inspired by the following geometric method.
Given the points $A$, $A'$, $B$, and $B'$, construct the
parallelogram $AA'B''B$, that is, $B''$ is the result of translating $B$ by the same translation that takes $A$ to $A'$.

Now angle $\angle B''A'B'$ is the angle of rotation.
If the transformation is truly a rotation, then
$\lvert A'B' \rvert = \lvert A'B'' \rvert = \lvert AB \rvert$
and triangle $\triangle B''A'B'$ is isosceles with base $B''B'$.

Construct triangle $\triangle APA'$ with base $AA'$ similar to $\triangle B''A'B'$
such that the orientation of the two triangles is the same if we
correspond $A$ with $B''$ and $A'$ with $B'$.
Then $P$ is the center of the rotation.